# JMeter - Call JMeterContextService addTotalThreads function impact

Tags: scripting, jmeter

There's an option to call

According to [javascript](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) function you can call static functions in JMeterContextService as:

```
Java.type("org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService").getTotalThreads()
```

JMeterContextService have static function [addTotalThreads](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterContextService.html#addTotalThreads-int-),
I tried to add threads but it didn't impact threads executed, what is the impact of calling it? code:

```
${__javaScript(Java.type("org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService").addTotalThreads(2))}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is internal and only used to increase count.

To add thread you can use this code on ThreadGrpup:

> ctx.getThreadGroup().addNewThread( ramp_time, ctx.getEngine() )

Don't use Javascript, prefer Groovy

Comment: Is this context specific to thread group or can be access across thread groups ?